# How to animate expand/contract instead of up/down

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I'm trying to get this line to behave like a ray of sun, moving diagonally right down (↘) and left up (↖). What I've got is up/down, despite using height reduction.

Preview in GIF (created with image editor):

[image: animation preview]

```css
body {
    background-color: grey;
}

.sunray {
    height: 200px; 
    width: 5px;
    background-color: white;
    opacity: 0.9; 
    filter: blur(5px);  
    transform: rotate(135deg); 
    position: relative;
    left: 60px;
    top: -50px;
} 
   
.sunray {
    animation: ray 1s linear infinite;
    animation-direction: alternate-reverse;
}
   
@keyframes ray {
    from { height: 200px; }
    to   { height: 50px; }
}
```

```html
<div class="sunray"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
}

.container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: 1px solid black;
}

.sunray {
  height: 200px;
  width: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0.9;
  filter: blur(5px);
  position: relative;
  left: 60px;
  top: -50px;
}

.sunray {
  animation: ray 1s linear infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate-reverse;
}

@keyframes ray {
  from {
    transform: translate(-50px, -50px) rotate(-45deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sunray"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you try my example without the 135deg angle on the div, you'll see what I mean.. Thanks.

Comment: @Amg, what do you think about this? I highlighted the container.

Comment: That's it. Thanks. I just need it right in the corner.

Comment: @Amg, wait a moment, I am going to try to <del>remove the container</del> move the transform back to the `.sunray`.

Comment: I moved the `rotate(…)` back to the `.sunray`.